# Problem: Make rebuilds entire project after switching branches in Git

Tags: makefile, git-branch

Best practice for Git, supposedly, is to experiment in branches and only merge that work into master when it seems perfect. But that slows my development cycle a lot, because switching branches in Git appears to touch every file, even those that don't change. The result is that `make` rebuilds the entire project from scratch, rather than only those files that have changed.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, Git does not update files that haven't changed when you switch branches.  I urge you to examine this assumption more carefully by looking at the modification times before and after switching branches, for files that have and have not changed.  If it's really the case that timestamps are changing for files that don't change, you may need to figure out what's wrong with your Git.

If the file modification times don't change, but everything is still rebuilding, then you have a problem with your makefile.

If you discover that Git is indeed only updating the timestamps on files which have changed, but these files are central to your system and causing massive rebuilds, then you might consider using `git worktree` to keep different branches in different worktrees so you don't have to switch back and forth between them in the same directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is in C/C++ or objectiveC and the cause is that the makefile (project file) is slightly modified across branches, [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org/) will be of great help. This tool remembers the actual compilation settings for each C file, and caches the resulting obj file. When you rebuild the project, the compiler may be skipped on file-by-file basis even if the makefile was modified.